# Weak convergence in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Does anyone have a reference for the following statement or similar ones?
Let $U$ be an open bounded set in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $f\in C^0(U\times S^1)$. Then the sequence $f_m (x):=f(x,mx_i)$ convergences weakly (in $L^1(U)$) to
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{S^1}f(x,t)~\mathrm dt
$$
Many thanks.

Comment: maybe you should use a different index letter since n is already the dimension of U. Also, what is $x_i$?

Comment: Thanks, I'll change $n$ to $m$. $x_i$ denotes the $i$-th component of $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I was able to answer the question, so there is no need to look at the question again. Thanks.